# Show invisible characters as code point box in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux

As shown in the image below, `tmux` cann't show control character `\0x1`, i.e. `C-A` as `Termite` or `Gnome-Terminal`. Is there any option to turn on showing invisible character, or is it related to `TERM` and  `terminfo`?

[image: tmux,termite,gnome-terminal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `tmux`'s behavior is the correct one; `GNOME Terminal` and `Termite` (actually their underlying `VTE` widget) is [buggy](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403130).